# django deployment with apache and mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache, deployment, mod-wsgi, centos7

In order to deploy my django project, i've downloaded httpd and mod_wsgi. To configure this module, I've also downloaded apxs and gcc and I've followed this tutorial : 
https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-configuration-guide.html
And then I've found in the django documentation :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/
a way to deploy my project. 
So I actually have this wigs.py :

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "ProjetIML.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And this httpd.conf :

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ninon/ProjetIML/ProjetIML/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/ninon/ProjetIML

<Directory /home/ninon/ProjetIML/ProjetIML>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Then I've restart the apache server with "apachectl restart" and when I try to access my site with localhost:80 nothing append. Did I miss something ? 
I've seen many posts explaining that they have coded files like "django.wsgi" but I haven't found anything about it in the django documentation. 
I've also tried to add a Virtual host like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ninon/ProjetIML/ProjetIML/wsgi.py
    WSGIPythonPath /home/ninon/ProjetIML

    <Directory /home/ninon/ProjetIML/ProjetIML>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But the apache server didn't want to restart.

Comment: What do you mean, it didn't "want to" restart? What happened when you tried? Did you get an error?

Comment: Yes, I got an error but I've found that all my files were located in a session with a password so I've put them into data and it works :) thx for your comment !